# Character replacement using awk

Tags: replace, awk, sed

Need to replace x in third column for first five characters.

input.txt:

```
1,abnil,1234567890  
2,asde,1472583691  
3,fghtr,3697412587
```

output.txt:

```
1,abnil,xxxxx67890  
2,asde,xxxxx83691  
3,fghtr,xxxxx12587
```

Comment: Can you post your attempt to do this, and where you are running into difficulties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an awk way with `sub()` function would be:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=',' '1+sub(/^.{5}/,"xxxxx",$3)' file
```

you can "overwrite" the first 5 characters too:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=','  '$3="xxxxx" substr($3,6)' file
```

Note that for the 2nd cmd, if the 3rd column has length less than `5`, it will be set by `xxxxx` too.

both one-liners give same output.

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue

replace any chars (not just digits), you can do this

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{sub(/...../,"xxxxx",$3)}1'
```

if you have fewer than 5 chars in that position, the replacement won't take place.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/[^,]{1,5}([^,]*)/xxxxx\1/3' file
```

or if you prefer:

```
sed 's/[^,]\{1,5\}\([^,]*\)/xxxxx\1/3' file
```

This replaces the first five non-commas (or less) of the third group of non-commas on a line with `xxxxx`.